# Android: Empty error message in onFailure of AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, asynchronous, error-handling, httprequest

I use an http client library for Android which can be found here: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/.
The problem is when I want to deal with the failure such as internet connection error. I could not get the error message from the handler method:

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(..., params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Why e.getLocalizedMessage() or e.getMessage() is empty?

Answer (score 1):

this should help:

```
            @Override
        public void onFailure ( Throwable e, JSONObject errorResponse ) {
            String msg = "Object *" + e.toString() + "*" + errorResponse.toString();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).setMessage(msg).setCancelable(false).setTitle("Fehler").setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).create().show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure ( Throwable e, JSONArray errorResponse ) {
            String msg = "Array *" + e.toString() + "*" + errorResponse.toString();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).setMessage(msg).setCancelable(false).setTitle("Fehler").setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).create().show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure ( Throwable e, String errorResponse ) {
            String msg = "String *" + e.toString() + "*" + errorResponse;
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).setMessage(msg).setCancelable(false).setTitle("Fehler").setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).create().show();
        }
```